# Should a json file that changes every 5 minutes be hosted by Flask or nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask

I understand the concept that nginx should host my static files and I should leave Flask to serving the routes that dynamically build content. I don't quite understand where one draws the line of a static vs dynamic file, though.

Specifically, I have some json files that are updated every 5 minutes by a background routine that Flask runs via `@cron.interval_schedule` and writes the .json to a file on the server.

Should I be building routes in flask to return this content (simply return the raw .json file) since the content changes every five minutes, or should have nginx host the json files?  Can nginx handle a file that changes every five minutes with it's caching logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since generating the file appears to have no relation to the request / response cycle of a Flask app, don't use Flask to serve it.  If it *does* require the Flask app to actively do something to it for every request, then do use Flask to serve it.